# Help trying to generate tricky multidimensional array format

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble trying to build an array in PHP which will output in the JSON format I am looking for. I will show you what I am trying to achieve and where I have got to so far:

```
[
    {"data":[{"x":3,"y":0},{"x":10,"y":0}]},
    {"data":[{"x":11,"y":0},{"x":13,"y":0}]},
    {"data":[{"x":12,"y":1},{"x":17,"y":1}]}
]
```

I am looping through db results and trying to build arrays to output the above json, my php looks like this (which is obviously not right yet):

```
//build the data
                    $data = array(
                                array(
                                    'x' => $age_start, 
                                    'y' => $ill_type
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'x' => $age_end, 
                                    'y' => $ill_type
                                )
                            );

                    $illnesses[] = $data;
```

This code outputs the following json:

```
[
   {
     [
        [{"x":2,"y":6},{"x":2,"y":6}],
        [{"x":2,"y":6},{"x":5,"y":6}],
        [{"x":4,"y":6},{"x":4,"y":6}]
    ]
  }
]
```

Any pointers on this would be great!

Comment: is that different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854138/help-using-json-encode-to-produce-specific-format)?

Comment: slightly - trying to build the array structure properly inside a loop, ITroubs has fixed the issue in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you know your desired JSON output already, you can simply [`json_decode`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to get it's representation in PHP. The [`var_export`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function prints the structure in parseable format. You can also use `print_r` or `var_dump` to dump the structure though.

```
$json = <<< JSON
[
    {"data":[{"x":3,"y":0},{"x":10,"y":0}]},
    {"data":[{"x":11,"y":0},{"x":13,"y":0}]},
    {"data":[{"x":12,"y":1},{"x":17,"y":1}]}
]
JSON;

var_export( json_decode($json) );
```

The above approach is universal. Just decode and dump the structure. Then assemble your code to create this structure and encode.

Comment: Wooosh. Went completely over my head =(

Comment: Yes - the `json_decode` will generate the correct PHP structure :) I like it

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
$data['data'] = array(
        array(
                'x' => $age_start,
                'y' => $ill_type
        ),
        array(
                'x' => $age_end,
                'y' => $ill_type
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON string, you can see that:

- it is an array (it is surrounded by `[` and `]`)
- each element is an object (surrounded by `{` and `}`)
- the objects have an element `data` that is itself an array
- that array consists of two objects with an `x` and a `y` property

It is important to know that a JSON object is represented in PHP by an associative array (when `json_encode()`'ing, `json_decode()` has a specific parameter to use either a `stdClass` or an assoc. array).
So the php structure looks like this:

```
$data = array(
  array('data' => array(array('x' => 3, 'y' => 0), array('x' => 10, 'y' => 0))
  ,array('data' => array(array('x' => 11, 'y' => 0), array('x' => 13, 'y' => 0))
  ,array('data' => array(array('x' => 12, 'y' => 1), array('x' => 17, 'y' => 1))
);
```

Comment: JSON objects are only represented as associative arrays if you put the second argument to `json_decode` to TRUE. Otherwise they are StdClass objects. What you mean is, associative arrays in PHP are encoded to JSON objects. Apart from that tiny nitpick, +1.